# unity3d, Enable / Disable Gameobject on hierarchy when the scene start

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

Objective:

- how to not show the gameobject when i start the scene?

i had success to make the "explosion" in gameobject, and i success to call it when i need. but the problem is the gameobject is calling from hierarchy. so it will show out on start without any trigger(not the clone).

or is that possible i can disable the game object(animation) at start, just use condition to enable it, after run 1 times, it disable again?

thanks for helping!

Comment: You said it's an "explosion"...does that mean it's a particle system? If so, there's an option for "Play on Awake" that will cause it to do what you describe. Try disabling that.

Comment: Can you just use `renderer.enabled=false` in `Start()`?

Comment: @Jerdak, thanks, your hint let me done all thing i need. thanks a lot. please post the answer in proper way to let me able to accept your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below is the solution.

renderer.enabled=false in Start()